# I put the things back

Tags: verb-forms

I putted the diapers, clothes, wet tissues and gloves back to the place.

Can I say "*I put the things back.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I put the things back" is a correct sentence.

The past tense form of *put* is *put*, not *putted*.  That is, the same sentence is either present or past tense, depending on context.

*Putted* is the past tense of *to putt* — the way golfers lightly hit the ball when it is close to the hole.